# JSON conversion issue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

*I have  a json string  and another one. i have to append together, send to server and get user id. I am stuck in d middle. Appended string is not getting converted to NSURL.*

---

**Here is my code.**

```
- (void)convertingstringtojsondata
{
    NSArray *components = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:ismunicipality,mobilenumberstring,placestring,namestring,  nil];
    NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"is_municipality",@"ph_nbr",@"place",@"reg_name", nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",components);

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:components forKeys:keys];

    NSLog(@"dict %@", dict);

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA %@", jsonData);

    jsonData= jsonData;

  JSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"JSON STRING%@",JSONString);
}
-(void)sendjsonforregistration
{
 [self convertingstringtojsondata];

    registerwithserverstring = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"http://forthepeople.mcms.net.in/forthepeople_service/registration?reg="];
    [registerwithserverstring appendString:JSONString];

    NSLog(@" appended string %@", registerwithserverstring);

    NSURL *registerURL = [NSURL URLWithString:registerwithserverstring];

    NSLog(@"register URL%@", registerURL);

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:registerURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:0];
NSOperationQueue * queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response, NSData * data, NSError * error) {
    NSData * jsonData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:registerURL];

    NSLog(@"%@", jsonData1);

    dataDictionary1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData1 options:0 error:&error];

   NSLog(@"DATA DICTIONARY %@", dataDictionary1);

}];
}
```

---

**Problem:-**
The registerURL shows null value...

Comment: After a long debugging I got last string as follows: http://forthepeople.mcms.net.in/forthepeople_service/registration?reg={"reg_name":"ugh","place":"Malappuram","ph_nbr":"7204412649","is_municipality":"1"}  . But this one is not getting converted to NSURL.

Comment: hey Alvin, can you please tell me whether you want to send the data in GET or POST type. Why do you want to encode the Get query string in JSON?

Comment: Can you post Positive response of this Request, while successful registration?

Comment: @AlvinG, You can try your request with POST, if web service allows.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using`NSURLComponents` to construct your URL, it handles query parameter encoding correctly in the `NSURLQueryItem`s your provide to it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to encode NSString before converting to `NSURl`. you can do with this.

```
 NSMutableString* registerwithserverstring = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"http://forthepeople.mcms.net.in/forthepeople_service/registration/reg=?{\"reg_name‌​\":\"ugh\",\"place\":\"Malappuram\",\"ph_nbr\":\"7204412649\",\"is_municipality\":\"1\"}"];

NSString * properlyEncodedString = [registerwithserverstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *registerURL = [NSURL URLWithString:properlyEncodedString];

NSLog(@"register URL%@", registerURL);
```

Output :

```
Printing description of registerURL:
http://forthepeople.mcms.net.in/forthepeople_service/registration/reg=?%7B%22reg_name%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%22:%22ugh%22,%22place%22:%22Malappuram%22,%22ph_nbr%22:%227204412649%22,%22is_municipality%22:%221%22%7D
```

Comment: @alvin G, let me know if you have still any problem

Comment: What new in this,even my answer also states what you have said.

Comment: @Vizllx, actually you said that `NSURL URLWithString:` is wrong but it is not wrong just need encoding before convert to nsurl.

Comment: Yes it is wrong as per  his code. I have just rectified what is wrong

Comment: Why need to allocate a new NSString  properlyEncodedString , when you can do this 1 line.

Comment: I don't know why peaple down vote to every one. if he/she have better answer then post it instead of down vote. here some one get stuck and we are here to provide help.

Comment: @Vizllx, what ever you write in single line. is also work same at compiler level. more are allocating object of NSUrl , actually that do not needed.

Comment: Yes, you r perfectly right mate, same happened to me someone just downvoted. Regarding single line code, I only mean it doesn't seem to necessary for such an easy stuff.